# Can user's custom JavaScript on MediaWiki call a Lua module?

Tags: javascript, lua, mediawiki, scribunto

On MediaWiki wikis each user has a user JavaScript page they can put code in, much like GreaseMonkey but without extensions. Such as at `User:YourUsername/vector.js`

MediaWiki has also had an embedded Lua, called [Scribunto](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), for a little while now.

I know Lua modules can be called from MediaWiki templates, and I suppose that's their main use. But Googling and hunting around the MediWiki docs I can't find whether there's a way to call a Lua module from your user JavaScript.

---

(I need to map names of languages to language codes in my JS and there's a Lua module to do just that without me duplicating the code (mainly data) in a second language.)

Comment: BTW, jquery.uls ships a langdb taken from CLDR.

Comment: @Nemo: That looks interesting - digging into it now ...

Comment: [Can I use jquery.uls on a MediaWiki wiki to get a language code from the name of a language in English?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29485489)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this directly, because JS runs on the client and Lua on the server. What you can do is to use [the MediaWiki API from JS](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/js/#!/api/mw.Api) to invoke the module. Specifically using [the `expandtemplates` API module](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=help&modules=expandtemplates).

For example, if you wanted to call the function `h2d` from [Module:Hex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module:Hex) with the parameter `FF` (`{{#invoke:hex|h2d|FF}}` in wikitext) and `alert` the result, then the JS would look like this:

```
var api = new mw.Api();
api.get( {
    action: 'expandtemplates',
    text: '{{#invoke:hex|h2d|FF}}'
} ).done ( function ( data ) {
    alert(data.expandtemplates['*']);
} );
```

---

And for the OP's specific case, running on the English Wiktionary:

```
var langName = 'Esperanto';
(new mw.Api()).get({
  action: 'expandtemplates',
  format: 'json',
  prop: 'wikitext',
  text: '{{#invoke:languages/templates|getByCanonicalName|' + langName + '|getCode}}'
}).done(function(data) {
  alert('Language name: ' + langName + '\nLanguage code: ' + data.expandtemplates.wikitext);
});
```

(`prop: 'wikitext'` avoids a warning from the API and lets you access the result as `data.expandtemplates.wikitext` rather than the slightly mystifying `data.expandtemplates['*']`. Otherwise there's no difference.)

Comment: Yes I experimented and found this myself. Would you mind if I add the code that solves my specific problem to your answer since it wouldn't work in a comment but probably doesn't warrant a separate answer anyway?