# Can I use jquery.uls on a MediaWiki wiki to get a language code from the name of a language in English?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, internationalization, mediawiki, wikimedia

[WikiMedia has a jquery plugin called jquery.uls](https://github.com/wikimedia/jquery.uls) (Universal Language Selector) for choosing a language in all kinds of fancy ways.

All MediaWiki sites seem to have it available to the JavaScript running on them via `$.uls`. There is [documentation for the ULS extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UniversalLanguageSelector) but it seems to only concern itself with the server side and how an end user would interact with it.

I want to know if I can use it to obtain a mapping from the English name of a language (such as "Vietnamese") to the ISO 639 language code for that language (such as "vi").

I can't seem to find this in the docs or find a method that does this among the exposed interfaces. Is it there and I just can't see it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mw.config.get('wgULSLanguages')` to get an associative array where the keys are language codes and the values are language names in English.

[Here](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:UniversalLanguageSelector#Configuration) there are other options you could use with this extension as well.

Comment: No, you can see it mentioned in the question as not covering what I'm looking for. Unless you can point out the section that I can't see of course.

Comment: you can use `mw.config.get('wgULSLanguages')`, and you will get "an associative array where the keys are language codes and the values are language names in English". Isn't it what you needed? Or i might have miss understood something

Comment: I wasn't able to find that on my own. Let me play with it now ... Yes that is it! I want the code from the language name but that's still easy. Edit your comment above into the answer so I can vote it up. Thanks.